# I can't pass the parameter via redirect it shows 404 page not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I can't pass the parameters via redirect it shows 404 page not found

here is my **code**

```
 $data['menu_id']=$this->menu_model->menu_insert($menu_data);
    redirect('menu/1');
```

Comment: please write full url in redirect.

Comment: You may need to config your routes in routes.php http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html example: `$route['menu/(:any)'] = 'controller/function/$1';`

Comment: If you want `$data` available, it must be loading view instead, since redirect is next request that doesn't have `$data`.